# How to replace a value in a sorted JS Array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a sorted by date collection of Arrays. In these arrays, there is a value `date`, and this date is a title in my HTML view. Sometimes I can have multiples arrays with the same `date` value, which I don't want.

What I would like to do is, either find and replace the same `date` value directly in the collection. Or add an AngularJS parameter in my HTML view to run the same date value only once (ng-if something for example).

The basic idea is to group "users" who have the same date under ONE unique date title.

I tried this, but still unsuccessful:

```
//Arr is fill up in this function and sort by date after, it is a 
$scope Array.  snapshot is from a firebase request and contains all 
values needed to fill up Arr. This deleDouble() function is called in 
a loop. Just right after there is a sort() function.

$scope.deleteDouble = function(Arr, snapshot)
{

var tmp = Arr;

// Algo 1 : infinite loop

for(var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
{
    if(tmp.indexOf(snapshot.date) === -1)
    {
        console.log("IF DATE ALREADY EXISTS");
        $scope.Arr.push({date : '', name : snapshot.name, adress : snapshot.adress});
    }
    else if(tmp.indexOf(snapshot.date) > -1)
    {
        console.log("IF DATE FIRST TIME");
        $scope.Arr.push({date : snapshot.date, name : snapshot.name, adress : snapshot.adress});
    }
}

}

// Algo 2 : is not working

tmp.reduce(function(acc, el, i, arr) 
{
  if (arr.indexOf(el) !== i && acc.indexOf(el) < 0) 
        console.log("IF DATE ALREADY EXISTS");
        $scope.Arr.push({date : '', name : snapshot.name, adress : snapshot.adress});
    else{
        console.log("IF DATE FIRST TIME");
        $scope.Arr.push({date : snapshot.date, name : snapshot.name, adress : snapshot.adress});
    }
}, []);

// Algo 3 : same result : nothing !

tmp.reduce(function(dupes, val, i) 
{
    if (tmp.indexOf(val) !== i && dupes.indexOf(val) === -1) 
    {
       console.log("IF DATE ALREADY EXISTS");
       $scope.Arr.push({date : '', name : snapshot.name, adress : snapshot.adress});
    }
    else
    {
       console.log("IF DATE FIRST TIME");
       $scope.Arr.push({date : snapshot.date, name : snapshot.name, adress : snapshot.adress});
    }
}, []);
```

```
<div ng-repeat="u in users">
     
     <h3 style="color:#2C33BE;">{{u.date}}</h3>
           
        <ion-item>
             <div class="item-u">{{u.name}}</div>
             <div class="item-u">{{u.adress}}</div>
        </ion-item>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
uniqueDateSet = {};
tmp = Arr.filter(function(elem, idx, arr){
    if(elem.date in uniqueDateSet){
        return false;
    }else{
        uniqueDateSet[elem.date]='';
        return true;
    }});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is deleting the doubles, but how could i fill up `Arr` with my snapshot values ? The goal is still to keep all others datas but affect to the `date` value a `" "` instead of `snapshot.date`. To finally have a same size Array

Comment: i tried to manipulate your algorithme, but i can't figure out how to `push` what i would like to `push` when a double is detected..The problem with `Arr.filter()` is that is a loop, and my values are already coming from a loop, so this is not working...

Comment: `uniqueDateSet={}; for( ... Arr ...){ if (elem.date in uniqueDateSet) { elem.date=' ';}}`. so all multiples date in Arr was replaced with ' '.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unique filter to use uniqueness of a particular value.

Just include the library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
```

then include the module in your `app` module

`var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.filters']);`

Then your HTML will be

```
<div ng-repeat="u in users | unique: 'date'">

     <h3 style="color:#2C33BE;">{{u.date}}</h3>

        <ion-item>
             <div class="item-u">{{u.name}}</div>
             <div class="item-u">{{u.adress}}</div>
        </ion-item>
</div>
```

Here is a working link to [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/Guafoc8alHY39MAGFzSW?p=preview) in which you can work around and experiment.

Comment: Wouhaou thank you ! This seems to be exactly what i would like to do, my problem is i'm working on the ionic creator interface, to prototype my app. And it is not allowing to insert scripts..

Comment: If it does not allow you to insert script then you can download this library locally and then link it through in the same way you are linking angular.js or angular.min.js

Comment: Arf sorry, it was a miss-click, but i upvoted you, i think you answer could be helpful for someone who haven't my code editor constraint.

Comment: Perfect ! I successully add the script and it is working. But what I would like to do is apply the filter only on the title, is that possible ? It should shows a title with below a list of users who have the same date.

Comment: Arf, i've tried this `<h3 style="color:#2C33BE;">{{u.date | unique: 'date'}}</h3>`, but how could "unique filter", find doubles if it is not apply to the entire array... Mmh, I'm affraid "unique" can only delete doubles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148781/discussion-between-aka-and-memphis).